# What is the ConnectionString to create a OdbcConnection for an access mdb file

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, odbc, connection-string

I want to connect from c# to an Access MDB file by using Odbc.

When I try to execute

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(
    "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\temp\\test.mdb;");
```

I get the following exception:

```
exc {System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
   :
```

What's the Problem here? It complains about "Data source name not found and no default driver specified", but I specified a Driver?

I got the connectionstring with help from here http://www.connectionstrings.com/access#net-framework-data-provider-for-odbc

Comment: can you replace the path with `c:\\temp\\test.mdb` to `c:\temp\test.mdb` . then try it again.

Comment: @Hiten004: In C# either use a verbatim string and use simple backslashes or a normal string and use double backslashes: `@"c:\temp\test.mdb"` or `"c:\\temp\\test.mdb"`.

Comment: It could be the provider string that it does not recognise - it can be a bit iffy about that. Check here: http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007 looks like you have to use `Driver=`, not sure if that's the same as `Provider=` but the site seems to make the distinction for ODBC - maybe you are just missing an extension name from the driver name

Comment: The Jet ODBC provider is only accessible to 32 bit applications.  If your c# project's compile target is 64 bit (any cpu), change it to x86.

Comment: HansUp is correct, I just found out myself and postet it as an answer. @Charleh: You use Driver= for Odbc and Provider= for OldDB. Their Connection strings are different and you can't use one for the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I just found the source of my Problem. I think others might encounter it as well:

I'm writing a .net application which runs in the 32bit .net vm when the OS is a 32bit Windows, and in the 64bit vm when the OS is a 64bit Windows. Using the 2 odbcad32.exe in syswow and system32 (yes both are named odbcad32.exe even though the one in system32 is for 64bit, and yes that's correct as well) I found out I only have the Access MdB Driver installed for odbc32 bit. So when my application runs on a 64bit Windows, .net wants to use the 64bit Version of odbc and doesn't find the Driver.

Ok, so now I need a 64 bit Access Driver, which does not exist according to this [enter link description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/dfbd0406-bc69-436e-998b-7fc454012f91). Ok the post is old, so maybe there exists one now?

When I force the Plattform in my Project Settings to x86, it works. Of course, this also forces my app to be run in the 32bit .net vm.

Comment: There is no 64 bit Jet driver.  If you want 64 bit, use the ACE driver instead of Jet. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255  Notice the ACE driver is available in both 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: ACE is also backwards compatible --- it supports the older Jet MDB format in addition to the newer ACCDB format.

Comment: I need to  connect the ODBC using DSN ..how to write?

Comment: I've got the very same error. But the 32-64-bit thing is not the source of it. For the DB driver management it is important to use the exact connection string `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=...;` or `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=...;`

Answer (score 0):

Use web config setting like example below

```
<add      name="ODBCDataConnectionString"   connectionString="Driver=ODBCDriver;server=ODBCServer;"   providerName="System.Data.Odbc"   />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a udl file, create your connection, and then open the file in notepad to see the connection string.  This has helped me out in the past -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Using this, you can create a regular connection like you would in odbc tool and verify that it works.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Isn't that for OleDB? I want Odbc.

Comment: I thought that this would work for odbc also, as long as the provider is installed on the machine.